# Deploying Sequential Workflow on Another Server

Tags: sharepoint-designer, visual-studio

I have created a sequential workflow using VS2010 which is a part of my Dashboard Solution. Now I want to deploy that Dashboard Solution to another Server. What I have done is, disabled the Workflow feature from the dashboard and deployed both the Features i.e, Dashboard.wsp and workflow.wsp on the server separately. I have done this using PowerShell.

I am able to deploy both the solutions but the problem is that when I associate my workflow with a library and add  a new document its gives an error in the History List saying "An Error has occurred in Workflow" Am I missing something while deploying because the workflow work fine locally.

Comment: Go to ULS log, filter out Category - Workflow Infrastructure and try to find any related record to your workflow. This should definitely give you a chance to find error. I would also suggest to check your WF if it is not depending on any specific user, group, permission, list, etc...

Comment: @luccio : Thanks for your reply can you please telme where can i find ULS log

Comment: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Logs
,I would recommend you to use sometool to display logs, i.e. https://sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com/

Comment: Did you find the problem? Can I post this as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to ULS log, filter out Category - Workflow Infrastructure and try to find any related record to your workflow. This should definitely give you a chance to find error. I would also suggest to check your WF if it is not depending on any specific user, group, permission, list, etc...

ULS log location: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Logs

I would recommend you to use sometool to display logs, i.e. sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com